# Check if .txt files are empty or not with azure adf pipelines using for each activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a folder in adls that is stored periodically with a bulk of .txt files containing header and data below.

I need to seek between all the files and get the ones that actually have data, I mean the second row not null. Then I need to delete the ones that have not data and keep the ones that brings values in order to send them into another pipeline.

I tried with lookup activity and their inner parameters like first row or skip line but no success, because that activity will group all the files into one single response, and I need to keep the files splitted in order to send them into another pipeline.

I was thinking in using metadata activity, retrieve all the files, then a for-each to filter them but an IF activity is not allowed inside for-each activity, so I don't know how to approach this...
any help would be great!

Comment: The file metadata activity should give you a list of files and their size. Then you can use a sinlge filter activity to identify files in that list with a specific size (i.e. a file size that tells you they are only headers). That will be much faster and simpler than using a for loop and lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF activity is allowed inside for-each activity.** To check .txt the files if it has data in it or not and then get the list of files with no data in it follow below steps.

- First use get metadata activity to get the all-filename s in the folder.
  [image]
  Dataset for get meta data activity.
  [image]
- Pass this child items to the for each activity as expression `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`
  [image]
- Under for each activity as Nandan suggested take lookup to view the data inside the file.
  [image]
  dataset parameter for lookup activity.
  [image]dataset for lookup activity.
  [image]
- The use If activity to separate files with no data using lookup activity output empty or not. with expression `@empty(activity('Lookup1').output.value)`
  [image]
- Under true condition add append variable to get list of empty files and add value as `@item().name`
  [image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! My problem was trying to do both metadata and lookup activities with the same dataset.... your solution worked perfectly! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

IF activity is supported within For activity.
So your suggestion of below framework is correct :

1. use get meta activity to get list of all files
2. for activity to iterate across each file
3. within for activity, use lookup on individual files and use if activity

Comment: That was the approach to solve it! thanks a lot! The problem was that I tryied to solve it using the SAME dataset for both activities... that was the main problem...