# Copy Data failing due to no new records found in source

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2, microsoft-fabric

I have a requirement where I am copying the data from a Blob storage source and staging it as .csv as I need some additional fields created through my pipeline. But, when there are no new records found in the source, a new file is being generated with additional column headers only which is causing my pipeline to fail.

Can someone help me to understand the best way to tackle this situation.

Note: This cop activity happens inside an "If Loop" and it seems like nested if loop does not work in Fabric or data factory.

Thanks!

I tried to approach it from different perspective but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Could you share your approach on how you have implemented the logic in your pipeline

Comment: are u copying your CSV to warehouse? can you please share screenshots of your copy activity (source, destination and Mapping tabs)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this situation, you can include a condition to check before copying the file from the source to the staging area. The condition should verify if the source file has new records, and only then should the copy activity occur.

- Since you are already using a copy activity inside the if activity, it is not possible to add a nested if activity within it. However, you can add two conditions (the first condition, which you already use, and the second condition for checking if records are present in the source file) in the same if activity and combine them using the `and` logical function. Inside that if activity, you can add the copy activity. This will ensure that the copy activity takes place only when records are in the source file.

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77051375/19986107) by Pratik Lad to check if the file is empty before copying.
You can use the expression like this in the if activity: `@and(<condition-1>,<condition-2>)`.

[image]

Replace `<condition-1>` with the same condition you have provided. Replace `<condition-2>` with the expression `not(empty(activity('Lookup1').output.value))`. This expression is similar to the expression given in the above link and modified for this requirement.